# One device loses ethernet connectivity randomly

Tags: networking, router, ip, airplay

I have an issue with one of the devices on my network, where it (seemingly) randomly loses it's ability to communicate on the network.

The device is a Bang & Olufsen BeoPlay A8 smart speaker and it is connected to my network with an ethernet cable.

When the speaker has lost it's connection to the network, it has it's normal green status light on the front and it's normal white LED on the top (which I understand is meant to mean that the speaker is happy and connected -- as far as it is concerned, anyway...).

The symptoms are:

- No longer listed in the list of AirPlay speakers on my iPhone and Macs
- No longer listed in the output of `dns-sd -B _raop` from my Macs
- Cannot ping the speaker's IP address
- DHCP server no longer lists it as an active device
- The MAC address for the speaker seems to vanish from ARP cache

  ```
  $ cat /proc/net/arp | grep 192.168.10.102 # <-- IP of the speaker before it loses connection
  192.168.10.102   0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0`
  ```
- My network switch (NetGear GS110TPV3) shows the port where the speaker is connected as being up and connected at all times

The only way to get the speaker back on the network is to physically remove power from it and re-apply power to force it to restart. Simply removing the ether cable and reinserting it doesn't seem to be enough to trigger the speaker to restart the necessary services to put it back on the network.

Things I've tried:

- Replace the DHCP server on the network

  Normally, I use the DHCP server on my ISP's router. I setup a replacement DHCP server on a Raspberry Pi (and disabled the DHCP server on my ISP's router) but the same issue occurs.
- Replacing the cable used to connect the speaker.

  I have tried multiple different Cat6 and Cat5 cables and I get the same issue with all of them. Some were pre-made patch cables and some cables I've made myself.
- Changing my switch from auto-negotiating the port to manually configuring it

  I've tried all of the available options, but I still get the same issue.
- Setting up a 'test bed' network with just the speaker, a Raspberry Pi and an old router as a switch and DHCP server

  To my surprise, I did not get the issue occurring on this test network. This therefore tells me that the issue is something to do with something on my network, but I cannot think of anything that would cause another device to fall off the network.
- Decreasing the DHCP lease time

  My theory was that the speaker is timing out in someway and giving it a DHCP lease that's only one hour long might make it stay active enough to not timeout. This didn't work.
- Factory resetting the speaker
- Contacting the manufacturer

  As the device is well out of warranty, I'd have to return it to the manufacturer and repairs and shipping would be at my cost.

  My concern with doing this is that it's a waste of time as I doubt the issue would occur for the manufacturer as the issue seems to be isolated to my network (see above).
- Logging pings to the speaker and to something else on the network

  I have it pinging my router and the speaker at the moment.

  I was trying to see if the whole network drops (maybe momentarily) when the speaker drops off the network. However, the logs showed that pings to the router continue with no interruptions and no increase in latency when the speaker drops off the network.

  In a previous attempt at logging pings, I was pinging the speaker and a smart TV on the network (one which has AirPlay functionality). I found that around the time that I turned the smart TV on in a morning was *around* (but not precisely) the time that the speaker lost it's connection. However, this is not reproducible.

  This issue happened last night and the ping log tells me that the speaker lost connection at 01:10:15 -- which is *around* the time that I turned **off** the smart TV. So this tells me that it's not the powering **on** of the smart TV, but still could be something to do with the smart TV.
- Set a static IP for the device

  I have attempted to set a static IP for the device. However, it only appears to allow the IP to be configured when using WiFi (ridiculously).
- Update firmware for the device

  There's been no updates for this device for several years now and it's already using the latest version.

**My question: What can I do to stop the device from losing it's connection?**

If anyone has any ideas on what could be causing this, or what I can do to troubleshoot further, please let me know.

Comment: imho, with the `around the time that I turned off the smart TV..` hint. I suggest to assign static IP to all network members. Assuming the subnet Mask is 192.168.10.XX ,assign all identified devices with 192.168.10.100++. And let the <100 be used with new/occasional/guest device. | I don't have a device, but https://support.bang-olufsen.com/hc/en-us/articles/360050974611-The-network-button-of-my-Beoplay-A8-is-solid-orange-what-can-I-do- doesn't really say whether or not the A8 IP is fixable or not. but it does mention the 'poor signal from the AirPlay', and recommend to update firmware .

Comment: @p._phidot_ Thanks. I should have mentioned that I have attempted to set a static IP for the device. However, it only appears to allow the IP to be configured when using WiFi (ridiculously). I have also tried to update the firmware, but there's been no updates for this device for several years now and it's already using the latest version. I'll add these things to the question so it's clear for others.

Comment: If the link light on the router shows it still connected, then it's probably not a hardware issue with the network.  Possibly the speaker is crashing and just becomes unresponsive.  Maybe cpu/ram failure in the speaker or the old unpatched firmware has a bug that causes it to crash?

Comment: @user10489 Yeah, I agree. That's my take on things. If it wasn't for the fact that the issue doesn't occur on an isolated network, I'd be able to let it lie a bit better. However because it only seems to happen on my network, it leads me to think that something on my network is triggering it, thus there's something I can do to prevent the bug from being triggered. I just can't think of anything else to try.

Comment: If something on the network is poking at and crashing the speaker, there are only two solutions.  1) find the device and remove or reconfigure it 2) get a firmware update for the speaker that doesn't crash when it is poked.  !3) put the speaker on an isolated network...but that's not useful.

Comment: @user10489 I think you've poked _me_ to take that action! :D I've been putting it off, but I think I should do it now. Thanks

Comment: an option b for `Logging pings` (where we only ping for known IP), u may try to log the [ipscanner](https://angryip.org/) to 'see' how the network members IP addresses behave..

Comment: I can't see how QOS would cause a device to suddenly and permanently stop responding to ping.